# Alternative way to download and install Ubuntu Touch (dual boot) on Nexus 4

Tags: installation, dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, android, nexus-4

Since I have connection issues (I live in China, where nothing will download properly except if provided a mirror inside China), I have downloaded the **Clockworkmod Recovery image for mako**, the **installer.zip**, and followed the instructions inside **dualboot.sh** manually: I had Cyanogenmod so SU was already there, etc. The situation now is, I have the **Ubuntu Dual Boot apk** installed on Android, and running fine.

But now I have a connection issue I cannot solve: the download is getting started, the small images like **image-master.tar.xz** and **image-signing.tar.xz** downloaded fine, but I haven't been able to download the big image **ubuntu-[long-hashtag-i-wont-copy-here].tar.xz**.

So my question is, is there another way to download this image (if there is only one, I don't know what comes next) and to flash it manually?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the issue downloading the big tarball? does it just stop? does it throw an error?

Comment: It just stops... I let it on all night and it just went back to "Install Ubuntu" as if I never pressed the button...

Comment: i just need an url...

Comment: What guide are you following...?

Comment: Just the official one: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation but this guide is really about unlocking the phone, rooting it, installing the SuperUser and Ubuntu Dual Boot apk in Android, there is not much about what happens next, as this is supposed to work smoothly once the phone downloads the tarball, but for me it just never happens...

Answer (score 1):

The system-image server is running at: https://system-image.ubuntu.com/pool/